# "Invalid use of group function" for a TRUNCATE(SUM())/TIMESTAMPDIFF query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a database with this schema:

posts(**id:integer**, created_at:datetime, deleted_at:datetime)
posts_reasons(**post_id:integer**, **reason_id:integer**)
reasons(**id:integer**, weight:integer)

I'm looking to find the average time between `posts.created_at` and `posts.deleted_at` (also known as time to deletion) for every group of posts with a SUM of `reasons.weight` with a range of 10. Some sample results might be along these lines:

```
  Total Reason Weight (groups of 10)  |  Average Time To Deletion
--------------------------------------+----------------------------
                                   0  |  987.36
                                  10  |  872.01
                                  20  |  819.34
                                  30  |  742.77
```

and so on. I'm excluding posts where time to deletion is greater than an hour/3600 seconds to avoid outliers.

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
  TRUNCATE(SUM(reasons.weight), -1) AS 'Reasons Weight',
  AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at)) AS 'Avg Time To Deletion'
FROM
  posts
  INNER JOIN posts_reasons ON posts_reasons.post_id = posts.id
  INNER JOIN reasons ON reasons.id = posts_reasons.reason_id
GROUP BY
  posts.id,
  TRUNCATE(SUM(reasons.weight), -1)
HAVING
  posts.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at) <= 3600
ORDER BY
  TRUNCATE(SUM(reasons.weight), -1) ASC;
```

I've made sure that I don't have aggregate functions in a WHERE clause, given how common that particular issue is; I've also ensured the query is grouped on `posts.id` to make the `SUM(reasons.weight)` aggregate work correctly.

I'm still getting an "invalid use of group function" error. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aggregate functions in GROUP BY!

```
SELECT
  TRUNCATE(reasons.weight, -1) AS 'Reasons Weight',
  AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at)) AS 'Avg Time To Deletion'
FROM
  posts
  INNER JOIN posts_reasons ON posts_reasons.post_id = posts.id
  INNER JOIN reasons ON reasons.id = posts_reasons.reason_id
WHERE
  posts.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at) <= 3600
GROUP BY
  TRUNCATE(reasons.weight, -1)
ORDER BY
  TRUNCATE(reasons.weight, -1) ASC;
```

To further aggregate by an aggregated value, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT
    ReasonsWeight
  , AVG(TimeToDeletion) AS AvgTimeToDeletion
  , COUNT(*) AS PostCount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      TRUNCATE(SUM(reasons.weight), -1) AS ReasonsWeight,
      MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at)) AS TimeToDeletion -- This is per post ID here, aggregation does not matter
    FROM
      posts
      INNER JOIN posts_reasons ON posts_reasons.post_id = posts.id
      INNER JOIN reasons ON reasons.id = posts_reasons.reason_id
    WHERE
      posts.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.created_at, posts.deleted_at) <= 3600
    GROUP BY
      posts.id
  ) AS SRC
GROUP BY
  ReasonsWeight
ORDER BY
  ReasonsWeight ASC
;
```

Comment: But I'm looking for groups of 10 of the *total* reason weight (i.e. sum of reason weights), not for individual weights.